# Getting variable from class that uses input

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a window in tkinter that requires additional input for a name. To get this input I created a special messagebox that gets the input and has a button to confirm the input in the entry. I need to then get that variable from the class as the return value. The problem is that I do not know how to get such a value when the user could take however long they wish. What should I do? (The value I need to return is `extension_name`)

My current code:

```py
class ExtensionNamer(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        #Initialize the window
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        #Set basic window properties
        self.title("Extension Naming")
        self.geometry("300x100+{}+{}".format(x, y))
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.grab_set()
        #Create the widgets
        self.extension_name_label = Label(self, text="Extension Name:", font=medium_font)
        self.extension_name_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=.15, anchor=CENTER)
        self.extension_name_entry = Entry(self, font=normal_font, width=20, justify=CENTER)
        self.extension_name_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.confirm_button = Button(self, text="Confirm", font=normal_font, command=self.confirm)
        self.confirm_button.pack(anchor=S, side=LEFT)
        self.cancel_button = Button(self, text="Cancel", font=normal_font, command=self.cancel)
        self.cancel_button.pack(anchor=S, side=RIGHT)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)

    def confirm(self):
        #Confirm the extension name
        self.extension_name = self.extension_name_entry.get()
        if ".xt" not in self.extension_name:
            self.extension_name += ".xt"
        self.destroy()

    def cancel(self):
        #Cancel the extension name
        self.extension_name = "NewXT.xt"
        self.destroy()
...
    def add_tab(self, event=None):
        #Adds a new tab
        tab_name = ExtensionNamer(self, self.winfo_x(), self.winfo_y(), color_mode=self.color_mode)
```

Comment: The `ExtensionNamer` class should take a callback parameter. The `confirm()` method can call this when it confirms the entry.

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a callback function parameter to the class. When the user confirms the extension, this function will be called with the extension name.

This is similar to the way Tkinter widgets take a `command` parameter, and you use it the same way. When calling `ExtensionNamer()`, add a `callback=` argument that specifies the function that will use the extension name after the user has confirmed it.

```
class ExtensionNamer(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y, callback, *args, **kwargs):
        #Initialize the window
        super().__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.callback = callback
        #Set basic window properties
        self.title("Extension Naming")
        self.geometry("300x100+{}+{}".format(x, y))
        self.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.grab_set()
        #Create the widgets
        self.extension_name_label = Label(self, text="Extension Name:", font=medium_font)
        self.extension_name_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=.15, anchor=CENTER)
        self.extension_name_entry = Entry(self, font=normal_font, width=20, justify=CENTER)
        self.extension_name_entry.place(relx=0.5, rely=.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.confirm_button = Button(self, text="Confirm", font=normal_font, command=self.confirm)
        self.confirm_button.pack(anchor=S, side=LEFT)
        self.cancel_button = Button(self, text="Cancel", font=normal_font, command=self.cancel)
        self.cancel_button.pack(anchor=S, side=RIGHT)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)

    def confirm(self):
        #Confirm the extension name
        self.extension_name = self.extension_name_entry.get()
        if ".xt" not in self.extension_name:
            self.extension_name += ".xt"
        self.destroy()
        self.callback(self.extension_name)
```

You would use it something like this:

```
    def add_tab(self, event=None):
        #Adds a new tab
        tab_name = ExtensionNamer(self, self.winfo_x(), self.winfo_y(), callback=self.display_name, color_mode=self.color_mode)

    def display_name(self, name):
        print(f'Extension name is {name}')
```

Comment: When I call the class how do I enable the callback? This currently gives the error `TypeError: ExtensionNamer.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'`

Comment: You pass the function that wants to use the name as another argument. I explained that in the answer, it's similar to the way you use `command=confirm` when creating the button widget.

Comment: `ExtensionNamer(master, x, y, callback=function_that_uses_extension_name)`

Comment: So `callback=confirm`?

Comment: No. `confirm()` is the function that calls the callback.

Comment: It's a new function that you have to write in the code that calls `ExtensionNamer`.

Comment: `add_tab` seems to be inside the `ExtensionNamer` class. It creates an instance of the same class?

Comment: No, it's a seperate function in the class `ExtensionEditor`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245649/discussion-between-trck-and-barmar).